# Getting all posts related data for a facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

For my web application - I need to fetch all the data for a particular facebook page. What kind of permissions do I need. Do I really need to create a canvas app for it?
 I dont intend to do anything on FB - but use some of the data available to arrive at some conclusions in my web based application which will be hosted on a server outside of FB.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook's API documents should provide everything you need:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page

According to the permissions section, you'll need either an App token or a User token.  Since you're talking server-to-server (I'm assuming this is server-to-server on account of the PHP tag), you're going to want to use an App token:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens

You should be able to create a Facebook App from within your Facebook account, which will provide you with an App ID and App Secret.  You can use those to make calls directly to the API.